# Passing data to and from C++ code using a python driver

Tags: python, c++, floating-point, ctypes

I am trying to pass arrays to a c++ function from a python driver.  One of the arrays I am passing to the c++ function is a results array.  I know the data is passing to the code correctly, but seems to be truncating on the way back.  I'm loosing my precision after the decimal.  Any ideas where I went wrong?  Below is a simplified version of the code, and the resultant output.

python code:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

def get_calculate_windows():
    dll = ctypes.CDLL('./cppFunctions.so', mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
    func = dll.calculate_windows
    func.argtypes = [POINTER(c_float), POINTER(c_float), c_size_t]
    return func

def calculate_windows(data, answer, size):
    data_p = data.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float))
    answer_p = answer.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float))

    __calculate_windows(data_p, answer_p, size)


###### MAIN FUNCTION #####

data = np.array(myData, dtype=np.float32)
ans = np.array(myAnswer, dtype=np.float32)

print ans[:10]
calculate_windows(data, ans, myLength)
print ans[:10]
```

c++ code:

```
extern "C" {

    void calculate_windows(float *h_data, float *result, size_t size ) {

        for (int i=0; i<size; i++ ) {
            result[i]=i/10;
        }

    }
}
```

output:

```
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

What the output SHOULD be:

```
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9]
```

Comment: `result[i]=i/10;            }`: Is there a reason for having about 12 spaces here?

Comment: messy editing.  I deleted a newline feed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know the data is passing to the code correctly, but seems to be truncating on the way back. I'm losing my precision after the decimal. Any ideas where I went wrong?

You are using integer division instead of floating-point division.

You can fix this by using:

```
result[i] = i / 10.;
```

Instead of:

```
result[i] = i / 10;
```